# UI issue when editing comments

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, user-interface, design

[Comment UI http://img5.glowfoto.com/images/2010/03/27-1808471743T.jpg](http://img5.glowfoto.com/images/2010/03/27-1808471743T.jpg)

Anyone else think that line looks a little funny? Due to the bad screen shot it appears solid but I think it's actually dotted. Either way, I understand small cancel link, [Fitts Law](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html) and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only an issue on meta, where we underline links in that way, so [wontfix] .. but, you bring up a good related point, in that the link DOES extend all the way across for no reason. So I'll look at that part of it.

Edit: you're right, this is kind of a minor bug, so changing to completed.. in addition to reducing the size of the cancel link, I also made the edit button itself use the pointer icon.

Comment: My guess would be it's set to display: block; somewhere in the CSS file. I'll click edit on this comment and check.

Comment: *all.css?v=6607 (line 1)* is what FireBug is giving me for the file name. Simply removing that *display: block;* corrects the issue with no other UI problems in FF 3.6. Though while the border bottom is set to dotted it isn't cleared when you hover (text-decoration: underline) so it's dotted **and** underlined when you hover.